# Redshift function syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have study this over and over, without figuring out what is wrong I feel like the syntax for this function is right

I have tried to take single quotes out of plpgsql, triple checked for commas, added body to  the dollar signs  with no luck, I can't figure out why this i erroring.  returns table should be the correct syntax right?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_ytd_costs_of_business (param1 date)
RETURNS TABLE (year INTEGER, month TEXT , revenue FLOAT8 ,transactiondate TIMESTAMP , Flag varchar(28),)
AS 
$$
BEGIN
select
  extract(year from transactiondate) as year
  , to_char(transactiondate, 'Mon') as month
  --, extract(month from transactiondate) as month_number
  , sum(netamount) as revenue
  ,transactiondate
  ,Flag
from
  vw_costs_of_businesss_copy a

--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ->=  concat(to_char(extract(year from '2019-01-01'), 'YYYY'),'01-01') --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))),'01-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(Cas(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as text ),'-01-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
--where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2019-06-07' and to_date(concat(to_char(Cast(extract(year from to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as Text),'0000'),'-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2019-01-01' --Convert the date param to year and concatenate with '01/01'
where to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= $1 and to_date(transactiondate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')>= to_date(concat(to_char(Cast(extract(year from to_date($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')-1) as Text),'0000'),'-01') , 'YYYY-MM-DD')

group by
  year
  , month
  ,transactiondate
 , Flag;

on a.
--order by  year;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

this is the error I am receiving:

> RETURNS TABLE (year INTEGER, month TEXT , revenue FLOAT8 ,transactiondate TIMESTAMP , Flag varchar(28),)

Comment: Would it be the leading comma `[...] Flag varchar(28),) [...]`?

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not it

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried removing the comma and got a different error.

Comment: @jmelesky what error code are you getting? I'm still getting the same one

Comment: It's still a syntax error, but it's at "on a.". If I remove that line, too, it gets into my DB without a problem.

Comment: I removed it but, it still shows Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "TABLE" 
Position: 75;

RETURNS TABLE (year INTEGER, month TEXT , revenue FLOAT8 ,transactiondate TIMESTAMP , Flag varchar(28))
        ^

Comment: Oh, what are you actually using? Some of the amazon services are only sort-of postgres.

Comment: Its amazon redshift, the client is using an out dated (one version older) postgres which doesn't allow for procs.

Comment: Okay, redshift isn't postgres at all, really. In this case, I'm pretty sure redshift user-defined functions can't return `TABLE`.

Comment: Oh man really? is there a work around I need to pass this as a param for a report.

Comment: I honestly don't know. Now that it's tagged 'redshift', you have a better chance at getting that answer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably because `TABLE` is not a valid RETURN type.

However, this is unimportant because **an Amazon Redshift User-Defined Function is not allowed to `SELECT` data from tables**. It can only operate on the data that is passed into the function.

See: [UDF Constraints - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-constraints.html)

Depending upon your use-case, a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) might be suitable. It would not "return" a table, but it could `CREATE INTO` a table.

Comment: Thank you I had come to this point, saw some documentation that this isn't possible and that redshift only works with scalar values in functions (really stupid), the issue is that I have to pass YTD and previous YTD as a param for a report.  I could still keep this as a SP and make a table to keep the data and have it be dynamic? ultimately thats what I need...

Comment: I don't quite understand your situation. Feel free to create a new Question explaining what you'd like to achieve, with a sample if possible.

Comment: from the Stored procedure, how do create a view or table from he result set?

Comment: It's in the documentation: [Supported PL/pgSQL Statements - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html)